# How to enable autocommit in python-mysql integration using mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, autocommit

I am working on a python project using mysql database integration by mysql.connector package.
I want to turn on autocommit but dont know how to do that.
This is how I connected with mysql:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="admin"
)
```

Please tell me how to turn on autocommit if you know so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example, you should use this line of code:

```
mydb.autocommit = True
```

This is in the documentation. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html